# Sammy.js + Mustache gives error in simple example: haystack.indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery, mustache, sammy.js

Hi all and thanks in advance for taking the time.

I'm experimenting with Sammy.js + Mustache . So, I have created an HTML file that includes everything that should be there:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sammy.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="mustache.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sammy.mustache.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="application.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've taken sammy and mustache files from their github sites.

In `application.js` there is simply :

```
$(function() {
    var app = $.sammy('#main', function() {

        this.use('Mustache','ms');

        var search = {};

        this.get('#search', function() {
            var ctx = this;
            ctx.load('data/server.json')
                .then(function(server) {
                    ctx.render('searchForm.ms', server);
                });
        });
    });

    app.run();
});
```

`searchForm.ms` is a very simple Mustache template.

It loads the json correctly, then loads the template, but it receives a Document instance. It passes this Document instance to Mustache which instead expects a String, so it fails with `haystack.indexOf is not a function` because haystack is a Document, not a string.

I also tried changing `searchForm.m`s to `searchForm.txt` and got the same error. I'm on a recent version of Firefox, working on `file://` urls.

However, this example is so simple it should not fail; where am I wrong?

Comment: Getting the same error using Mustache and jquery. Could you post the contents of the searchForm.ms template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is related with lastest jQuery versions (1.6+) and it's browser implementation. I am using lastest version of chrome browser (14.0.8....) and for some reason the success callback while loading template is returning an Document object while the logic for the Sammy framework expects a string. In version 1.4.2 of jQuery the type returned by this call is of type string in the same browser version.

Walking through the stack I found the issue at line 1499 in Sammy.js:

```
dataType: is_json ? 'json' : null,
```

Fixing it replacing null for 'text'

```
dataType: is_json ? 'json' : 'text',
```

I am not sure if this change is correct. But I hope this info can be useful

Answer (score 1):

Your template is not loading properly, or the other library is passing an object instead of a string.

```
Mustache.to_html({}, {}, {} );
```

Causes same error.

Comment: Yes, as I said "cause haystack is not a string, but a Document." I solved it patching Sammy.Mustache to check wether it is considered an XMLDocument, and in case serializing it to a string. However I was keeping this open cause I suppose I (we) are doing something wrong, but maybe at this point there is a bug.